# Movement in a dinamic board

Tags: c#

I have to create a board with the given length of x and y (“xBoardLenght” and “yBoardLenght”).  I will have several mines defined in the tuple "mines". I have as well the pair of x and y for start the game and finish (“starting” and “exit”. I’ll have to pass the “secuence” of movement in another list of m (movement forward 1 position) or r (movement rotating 90 degrees to the right) starting in the direction of the variable “initialDirection” (can be N, S, W, E). I’m lost because I don’t know how to move the position in the board and check if the box in the board is free or have a mine. This code have to return Success if reach the exit, Fail if reach a mine, not complet if it's still in the board or Out of limit. Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot.

```
        string[] secuence = new string[] { "m", "m", "m", "r", "m", "m" };
        int[,] starting = new int[0, 1];
        int[,] exit = new int[4, 2];

        string initialDirection = "N";

        int xBoardLenght = 4;
        int yBoardLenght = 5;

        Tuple<int, int>[] mines =
            {
            Tuple.Create(1, 1),
            Tuple.Create(3, 1),
            Tuple.Create(3, 3)
        };


        int[,] boardTurtle = new int[4, 5];

        //populating 2D Array
        for (int m = 1; m < xBoardLenght; m++)
        {
            for (int n = 1; n < yBoardLenght; n++)
            {
                boardTurtle[m, n] = 0;
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in mines)
        {
            boardTurtle[item.Item1, item.Item2] = 1;
        }
```

Comment: Why are variables `starting` and `exit` arrays? I believe you want them to represent points, so make them `Tuple`s. Or better, make them `Point`s to convey what they are supposed to be. You can use `System.Drawing.Point` or a custom implementation as it is very simple (if you don't need anything else probably `X` and `Y` properties would be just enough)

Comment: Because the starting and exit position are dynamically. I don't know how to move the point every time. Is it better doing with Point? Can you explain, please? Thanks

Comment: How do you intend to move the positions when they are arrays?

Comment: This is that I cant do because I have to move depends of the initial direction. The problem is that I don't know how to do with Points. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Point`s to hold the positions on the board. 
They have properties for `X` and `Y` coordinates. 
I'd use a custom `Point` struct with the ability to add them directly:

```
public struct Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public Point(int x, int y) { X = x; Y = y; }

    public static Point operator +(Point left, Point right)
        => new Point(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y);
}
```

Now you can represent moves using `Point`s.
Here I'm also using an `enum` to represent directions (the order is significant for later use)

```
public enum Direction { North, East, South, West }

// On a board which is an array the Y axis points downwards,
// so e.g. North direction is (X: 0, Y: -1)
Dictionary<Direction, Point> moves = new Dictionary<Direction, Point>
{
    { Direction.North, new Point(0, -1) },
    { Direction.East,  new Point(1,  0) },
    { Direction.South, new Point(0,  1) },
    { Direction.West,  new Point(-1, 0) },
};
```

---

The board is a separate entity and should reside in its own class - this is a simple implementation, you can add other functionality

```
public class Board
{
    // Enumeration representing the outcome of a move on the board
    public enum MoveResult { Good, OutOfBounds, MineHit, Exit }

    // State of individual points on the board
    enum State { Empty, Mine, Exit }

    public Point CurrentPosition { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; }
    public int Width { get; }
    State[,] board;

    public Board(int width, int height, Point initialPosition, Point exitPosition)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        // Usually multidimensional arrays are represented in a way 
        // contrary to a normal (X,Y) coordinate system,
        // usually someArray[row(Y coordinate), column(X coordinate)], not the other way around.
        // This also makes printing the array simpler if you need it.
        board = new State[Height, Width];
        CurrentPosition = initialPosition;
        board[exitPosition.Y, exitPosition.X] = State.Exit;
    }

    public Board(int width, int height, Point initialPosition, Point exitPosition, IEnumerable<Point> minePositions)
        : this(width, height, initialPosition, exitPosition)
    {
        foreach(var pos in minePositions)
        {
            board[pos.Y, pos.X] = State.Mine;
        }
    }

    // Make a move on the board and return a value indicating if the move was successful
    public MoveResult Move(Direction direction)
    {
        // Get the move from the dictionary
        Point newPosition = CurrentPosition + moves[direction];

        if(newPosition.X < 0 || newPosition.Y < 0 || newPosition.X >= Width || newPosition.Y >= Height)
        {
            return MoveResult.OutOfBounds;
        }
        if(board[newPosition.Y, newPosition.X] == State.Mine)
        {
            return MoveResult.MineHit;
        }
        if(board[newPosition.Y, newPosition.X] == State.Exit)
        {
            return MoveResult.Exit;
        }

        CurrentPosition = newPosition;
        return MoveResult.Good;
    }

    static readonly Dictionary<Direction, Point> moves = new Dictionary<Direction, Point>
    {
        { Direction.North, new Point(0, -1) },
        { Direction.East,  new Point(1,  0) },
        { Direction.South, new Point(0,  1) },
        { Direction.West,  new Point(-1, 0) },
    };
}
```

Then you can use this class for the board you need:

```
// using a Queue here as it fits better
// var sequence = new Queue<string>(new[] { "m", "m", "m", "r", "m", "m" }); // loss in this scenario
// var sequence = new Queue<string>(new[] { "m", "r", "m", "m", "r", "m", "m", "r", "r", "r", "m"}); // win
// a quicker way is to use chars instead of strings
var sequence = new Queue<char>("mrmmrmmrrrm");

var start = new Point(0, 1);
var exit = new Point(3, 2);

var initialDirection = Direction.North;
var currentDirection = initialDirection;

int boardWidth = 4;
int boardHeight = 5;

var mines = new List<Point>
{
    new Point(1, 1),
    new Point(3, 1),
    new Point(3, 3),
};

var board = new Board(boardWidth, boardHeight, start, exit, mines);

while(sequence.Count > 0)
{
    var move = sequence.Dequeue();
    if(move == 'm')
    {
        switch(board.Move(currentDirection))
        {
        case Board.MoveResult.Good:
            // normal move - do nothing
            break;
        case Board.MoveResult.OutOfBounds:
            // moved beyond the board - loss
            return;
        case Board.MoveResult.MineHit:
            // moved on top of a mine - loss
            return;
        case Board.MoveResult.Exit:
            // if you require the moves to go exactly to the exit, not beyond,
            // check whether the queue is empty here:
            if(sequence.Count == 0)
            {
                // win
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    else if(move == 'r')
    {
        // Rotate the direction 90° clockwise by adding 1 modulo 4 as there are 4 directions.
        // This requires the Direction enum to have directions in the right order.
        currentDirection = (Direction)((int)(currentDirection + 1) % 4);
    }
}
```

See all of this working [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wi61Hj).